# Save custom information on federated cookie issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, acs

Hi I am using acs federation in MVC4 application with form authentication. During login my application working perfectly to authenticate and redirect to home page after SSO via gmail etc. I want to save Agent ID of user whose email id matched with database recorded email.But the problem is that after some time agent id automatically remove and claim where I added AgentID removed and showing null during when I am trying to access Agent Id from other pages via this code.

```
((ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).Claims.Where(c => c.Type.Equals(ClaimTypes.Role)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Login method is below here when user redirect after enter gmail credentials.

```
     [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult SignIn()
    {
        UserRoles userObj=null;
        Customer customerObj=null;
        ClaimsIdentity identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

        var claimCollection = identity.Claims;
        Dictionary<string, string> tempClaims = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (Claim claim in claimCollection)
        {
            tempClaims.Add(claim.Type, claim.Value);
        }

        if (tempClaims["http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider"] != null)
        {
            string strIdentifier = string.Empty;


            if (tempClaims["http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider"] == "uri:WindowsLiveID")
                strIdentifier = tempClaims["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier"];
            else
                strIdentifier = tempClaims["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"];


            userObj = repository.Filter(f => f.EmailId.Equals(strIdentifier)).FirstOrDefault();


            if (userObj != null)
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userObj.Role));


                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.SerialNumber, userObj.AgentID.ToString()));




            }                

        }           


        return User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? RedirectToAction("Index", "Home") : RedirectToAction("Login");

    }
```

Comment: Please explain your problem better. The problem is that `AgentID` is sometimes null?

Comment: Actually problem is during SignIn, a new claim added such as identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.SerialNumber, userObj.AgentID.ToString())); But the problem is after some time that claim not persisted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have added the `AgentID` as a `ClaimTypes.SerialNumber` claim but you haven't persisted the new principal into the federation cookie:

```
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
var token = new SessionSecurityToken(principal);
FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(token);
```

The `WriteSessionTokenToCookie` will update the federation cookies with the custom claims you have added so that on subsequent requests you will be able to retrieve them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are augmenting the set of claims in memory but you don't persist in in a cookie again.

There are two options - either you DO manually persist your new claims identity but you just forgot to show the code or you DON'T save your changes to the federated cookie (which explains why your changes are lost).

Take a look at one of my tutorials where I show how to create the claims identity from scratch and persist it. I hope this gives you some ideas on what to do with your augmented identity:

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2012/09/forms-authentication-revisited.html